# Trying to replace a value with a string containing backslash \ in a file

Tags: string, shell, escaping, ksh

I could really use your help here.

**What I want to do** :
I have an *encrypted* password I want to write in a property file. Let's say I have this password stored in $password and I want to write it as value to a key named "passKey" in my.varfile file.

**Here's the command I used so far to do so** :
`sed -i "s|passKey=[^ ]*|passKey=$password|" /path/to/my.varfile`

**Problem** :
It worked just fine until I got an encrypted password containing a backslash \
=> what happens with it is that sed interprets the backslash as an escape character, thus messing with the password.

For instance, when I have a pass like : `205RjIiajQ\=\=`
It gets written in my file as : `205RjIiajQ==`

I tried many things, like replacing \ with a \\ in my password to actually escape the backslash, without success.

Any ideas on how to do this ?
I'm also open to suggestions such as trying to do it with anything else than sed.

*(Note that - unfortunately :p - I'm using **ksh** here, not bash)*

Thanks
T.

Comment: Use "205RjIiajQ\\\=\\\=" it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to use [pattern substitution (see section 4.5.4)](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch04_05.htm) to add an escape character (`\`) to each occurrence of `\` in `$password`.

Let's say we have the following password:

```
$ password='205R\\\jIiajQ\\=\='
```

OP's current `sed` solution (and incorrect result):

```
$ sed "s|passKey=[^ ]*|passKey=${password}|" file
passKey=205R\jIiajQ\==
```

Let's use parameter substitution to replace each `\` with `\\`:

```
$ password="${password//\\/\\\\}"       # we have to escape each `\` to keep it from being treated as an escape character
$ echo "${password}"
205R\\\\\\jIiajQ\\\\=\\=
```

OP's `sed` solution with this new `$password` (and correct result):

```
$ sed "s|passKey=[^ ]*|passKey=${password}|" file
passKey=205R\\\jIiajQ\\=\=
```

Here's a [ksh93 fiddle](http://tpcg.io/aI827jg7)

**NOTES**:

- once OP verifies this solution works the `-i` option can be added back into the `sed` command as needed
- if there's a need to maintain the original `$password` value, a new variable can be used to hold the 'escaped' string (eg, `newpwd="${password//\\/\\\\}" ; sed "s|....|passkey=${newpwd}|" file`)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really know about pattern substitution, but nice tip. Seems to work just fine now !